# React router component appears then disappears immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a component called main. this has this inside it:

```
<Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/categories">Category</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/basket">Basket</Link></li>
        </ul>

        <Route
          path="/basket"
          render={() => (
            <Basket
            />
          )}
        />

        <Route
          path="/categories"
          render={() => (
            <Categories />
          )}
        />
      </div>
    </Router>
```

I then click on categories and that renders the Categories component, which is just this:

```
const Categories = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/trainers">Trainers</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/rucksacks">rucksacks</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <Route path="/trainers" component={Trainers} />
      <Route path="/rucksacks" component={Rucksacks} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);

const Trainers = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Trainers</h2>
  </div>
);

const Rucksacks = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Rucksacks</h2>
  </div>
);
```

When i then click on Trainers or Rucksacks, the h2 element flashes on screen. i.e. appears then disappears instantly. why would this be?

what im trying to achieve is having a home page and then you can click on categories which renders all my categories and then you can click on sub categories which will render a list of products. any idea why this is being funky and not displaying/rendering correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have 1 router in your application.  Modify the categories component to use a Switch instead of Router:

```
const Categories = () => (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/categories/trainers">Trainers</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/categories/rucksacks">rucksacks</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <Switch>
        <Route path="/categories/trainers" component={Trainers} />
        <Route path="/categories/rucksacks" component={Rucksacks} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: looks like it wants to see the full paths, so /categories/trainers: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4428